# thyrsitor leakage

Tags: leakage-current, thyristor

I have built a circuit to switch  a thyristor* on and off .

The circuit is like the circuit below.
[image: thyristor]

when the gate is on all is right and the device is latched when the gate voltage is removed , but the problem that if I remove the connection of anode (+5v)(with Vcontrol = 5V) the circuit continues to conduct with Voltage of cathode = 0.55V.(VR2).

Maybe this voltage hasn't any effect but why that's happen?
is there any leakage current from gate to cathode !

*BT151 : 
[image: BT151 principle characteristics]

Comment: Your datasheet gives an Igt value of 2-15mA. You're seeing 5.5mA.  This is the 'leakage' current. For as long as you apply a voltage across the gate-cathode you'll see some current flowing.

Comment: Where did you think the gate current goes? Of course it must appear at one of the other terminals. Look at the internal structure of an SCR.

Comment: yes I look to the datasheet and I'm sure that the current is generated from the gate and it isn't from the air , but it's unbelievable in the work principle of transistor that there's a current emitter if no voltage is applied to the collector.
if Ic=0 without looking to Ib , Ie=0;
if we look to the load line of transitor we are on cutoff there's no current

Comment: like my recent question no definitive answer